# How do I calculate the time complexity of this code?

Tags: java, algorithm, hashmap, time-complexity

I've built a data structure that receives an array list of documents (ArrayList<ArrayList> documents) and I need to store each subsequent words in a data structure and how many times the subsequent has appeared.

So I built a HashMap that has the two strings concated as the key and how many times they've appeared as value.

Here's my code:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> counter; //Treat as its initialized

public add(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> documents){

      for(ArrayList<String> doc : documents){
          for(int i=0; i<doc.size-1; i++){

              String concated = doc.get(i)+doc.get(i+1);
              counter.compute(concated, (k,v) -> v==null ? 1 : v+1);
           }
        }
```

Whats the time complexity of this and how do you calculate it? and could've I made this algorithm faster in anyway?

I tried watching youtube videos about the Big O but none of the videos go into complex situations like this.

Answer (score 2):

The time complexity of your code can be understood as follows:

The outer loop (i.e., for(ArrayList doc : documents)) will run as many times as there are documents in your input list. So if there are n documents, this loop runs n times.

The inner loop (i.e., for(int i=0; i<doc.size-1; i++)) will run as many times as there are words in each document. So if there are m words in each document, the inner loop runs m times.

So overall, the time complexity of your code can be considered as O(n*m).

However, this is not the final complexity. The HashMap operation counter.compute() also has a time complexity which is usually O(1) in the average case but can be O(n) in the worst case where n is the number of elements in the map. But since HashMap operations are generally considered to have a time complexity of O(1) in average case scenarios, we usually consider the time complexity of your code to be O(n*m).

In terms of improving your code:you can use a pair of strings as the key to your HashMap instead of concatenating the strings(You can create a simple Pair class for this purpose) or u can use the Map.merge() method instead of Map.compute().These will make it easier to manipulate and understand. But these changes are not going to change the time complexity of your code.

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity of your code can be calculated as follows:

1. Your outer for loop iterates over n documents in the given ArrayList (`O(n)`)
2. The inner for loop iterates m times over the current document (`O(m)`)

Therefore, I would say the time complexity of the provided code snippet is `O(n * m)` in the worst case, where "n" represents the number of documents and "m" represents the average size of the documents.

Good luck!

Comment: The last line should be removed - then this is a fine answer. The last line makes no sense. The string conatenation is irrelevant here (it's just 2 strings, not 'a string that is being continually grown'), and isn't `O(n)`  given that you defined `n` to be the number of documents in the list. Even if it was, `O(n+n)` is simply `O(n)`, so removing one `O(n)` from that doesn't change the big-O notation at all. I don't think the line is necessary nor that it can be salvaged. Just remove it.

Answer (score -1):

We would normally say that this code is O(n) in the size of the input.  The "size of the input" is the number_of_documents + total_document_strings + total_string_length;

It's not possible to do better than that in the worst case, since it takes that much time just to read the input, and in the worst case you have to read it all.

Technically, though, it's O(n) *expected* time, because the `HashMap` operations are O(1) expected time.  The word "expected" implies that the hash function is treated as random, but in fact it is not and an adversary who knows the hash function could maliciously devise inputs that take more than O(n) time.  We often don't worry about this distinction.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. There are 2 loops here; you can't reduce this down to `O(n)` unless you decree that one of these loops is to be treated as constant.

Comment: The answer is fine.  I don't think you're considering the definition of 'n'.